# What is a good workaround for this error? ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to run a merge from a 'temp' table (interchange_data) from my local database to send data to a 'clone' table across a database link. When i run the merge, i am receiving the following error:

**ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables**

I know that it may be because i have duplicate records (based off what i read), but i am not sure how i would be able to remove duplicates without a distinct row_id. I've tried putting a DISTINCT in to see if that would help to no avail. Any advice / general direction would be greatly appreciated. Below is my merge code:

```
MERGE INTO db1.IN_DATA@ora Y
USING
    (SELECT DISTINCT FROM,
            TO,
          "DATE_",
          TIMESTAMP_, 
            VAL,
            LOCAL_TIMESTAMP,
            LAST_UPDATE
    FROM    IN_DATA
  ) X ON (
            Y.FROM = X.FROM
            AND Y.TO = X.TO
            AND Y.TIMESTAMP_ = X.TIMESTAMP_)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
      SET Y.VAL                = X.VAL,
       Y.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = X.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT 
            (
          FROM,
          TO,
          DATE_,
          TIMESTAMP_,
          VAL,
          LOCAL_TIMESTAMP,
          LAST_UPDATE)
        VALUES   
         (X.FROM,
          X.TO,
          X.DATE_,
          X.TIMESTAMP_,
          X.VAL,
          X.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP,
          X.LAST_UPDATE);
```

Comment: Not a solution to this problem but it looks like you want a remote table to be synced.  You could try using a Materialised view in the target.

Comment: done, sorry. when i originally posted that title, the UI wouldn't let me use that title (for some odd reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you select more columns than only the columns used for matching, the DISTINCT clause cannot guarantee that the matching will yield unique matching columns.

Try to define a UNIQUE INDEX or UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the columns `"FROM"`, `"TO"` and `"TIMESTAMP_"` in table `"IN_DATA"`, if there is not already a such an index or constraint or a primary key.

Comment: In the table.`ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2, ... column_n);`